# Standard deviation image analysis

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, standard-deviation

I'm currently running a program in which a folder of images is read, these images are turned into .float64 values, and then I use those to find an average and standard deviation image. Then, I will map out the changes over time in the image, but that part comes after my issues. I have been tinkering with this for a while, and I have been hopelessly stuck on my standard deviation.

I've written out how the formula works, and I'm fairly sure that my code perfectly reflects that formula, but all of my values are coming out too high, so that when I try to display the image it is all completely white.

```
sumImg = []
imgList = []
```

Here, I will go through my folder, take the image files, convert them to float64, and use those values for the average image as well as making an image list for standard deviation.

```
for filename in files:
    img = Image.open("./data/" + filename)
    img = np.float64(img)
    imgList.append(img)
    
    try:
        sumImg += img
    except:
        sumImg = img
    
avgImg = sumImg/len(imgList)
```

This is where I believe my problem is, but I'm not sure. Somewhere in this math my values are growing to be much higher than they should be.

```
#standard deviation is:
#the square root of {(the sum of {(every number in your list minus the average) squared})
#divided by the number of items in the list minus 1}


stdImg = []

for image in imgList:
    try:
        stdImg += (image - avgImg)**2
    except:
        stdImg = (image - avgImg)**2
        
stdImg = np.sqrt(stdImg/(len(imgList)))

stdImg = np.clip(stdImg, 0, 255) 
stdImg=np.uint8(stdImg)
mplot.imshow(stdImg)
```

After this all that is left is to compare the standard deviation to a user defined threshold and highlight any areas that exceed the threshold, which would indicate movement over the list of images. I'm new to Python, so it's probably a simple mistake somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved, images weren't being added to a list, had to replace .append() with .insert()